# failure to install ubuntu-restricted extras

Tags: ubuntu-restricted-extras

I opened the terminal put in: sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras
run it
but the packet was not find.
I wanted to use this command to be able to watch .mpeg files.

I am using Ubuntu 21.04 LTS

Comment: Do you have all the repositories enabled? Are you sure you typed it correctly?

Comment: Both apt and apt-get work. But you need the repository multiverse in order for apt to find the restricted extras: `sudo add-apt-repository multiverse`; By the way, which version of Ubuntu are you running (20.04.x LTS or some other version)?

Comment: @24601 We've been using `apt` instead of `apt-get` for years. Not the problem here. Either a mistype, a EoL release or the repositories aren't enabled for some reason.

Comment: perhaps the op should [edit] the question and indicate which version/flavour of ubuntu is in use

Comment: There could be multiple reasons for your issue, but as you didn't provide any OS & release details, nor messages; we can only guess. If you're using a *supported* system the answer provided by chili555 should work, but it's not your only possible problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try:

```
sudo add-apt-repository multiverse
sudo apt update
sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

You should be all set.

Comment: It worked. Thanks!

Comment: If my answer has been helpful, please accept it: https://askubuntu.com/tour Those searching with the same problem will appreciate it.